# Prevent Acrobat reader from locking a pdf when it is open

Tags: pdf, locking, acrobat, file-locking

If someone has open a PDF with Acrobat Reader on his machine, nobody can save a new version of the file.

I am looking for a way to tell Adobe Acrobat reader not to lock the file for editing.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible in Windows: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/867994?tstart=0 See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910029/possible-to-make-adobe-reader-not-hold-a-file-lock-on-windows

Comment: another good reason not to use Windows. This is available on Unix for a while...